# Is this correct: no one will be asked to return until I am sure that the crisis has past

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Per the title, Should it be:

No one will be asked to return until I am sure that the crisis has **past**?

or

No one will be asked to return until I am sure that the crisis has **passed**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: It’s the second one, passed.

Passed is the past tense of the verb pass, and is to do with motion. “The car passed us.” Because there are no other verbs in the sentence it makes sense for passed to be used.

Past is a noun or adverb. As an adverb; “The car went past us.” Because went is a verb it makes sense to use the adverb past.

Hope this explains it.

https://www.oxfordinternationalenglish.com/passed-vs-past-whats-the-difference/

Comment: Please don't supply answers to very basic questions; it only encourages more off-topic questions here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh? Ok then. Is there a place I can get an idea of what’s off topic or not? Thanks.

Comment: @WilliamwithaJ, [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: Haven't you 'taken the tour' or visited the Help Center? Basically 'ELU was established for more basic questions' (but look at the high standard of some of the questions / answers _there_!) 'ELU is aimed at linguists ...'. I'd say questions most 10-year-old native speakers would be expected to be able to answer are well off-topic; those 16-year-olds armed with the recommended resources would be expected to answer, _often_ off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Cheers. That helps. Maybe there should be a large banner at the top saying to new people not to ask simple questions. That might help. The past/passed one might be a bit tricky, but it’s little more than a google search for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The second choice, "passed", is the correct one.

"Passed" is the past participle of the verb "passed". It is used with the auxiliary verb "to have". "Past" can be an adjective, adverb, noun, or a preposition, but it's not a verb. It can be used in many ways, but not as a verb form conjugated with "to have (has)".

There are subtle differences in meaning as well, but the giveaways here are the presence of "have", which indicates the function of the word as a verb in your sentences.

Here are a couple of references: [Writing Explained](https://writingexplained.org/passed-vs-past-difference) ("passed" vs "past") and 
[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/have#have__102) ("have" as an auxiliary verb).

Answer (score -1):

The bab.la site is helpful and reliable if you want to know how to conjugate verbs: (see https://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/pass)

> **Infinitive** : to pass
>
> **Present** Pass, I pass; he passes
>
> **Simple past** I passed; he passed
>
> **Present perfect** I have passed; he has passed
>
> **Imperative** 2nd pass; 1st Let´s pass
>
> **Present participle** passing
>
> **Past participle** passed

Comment: @Graybeard, I think you meant to write "I have passed"?

Comment: @IsabelArcher Ha! How embarrassing! I've edited.